# Why do we need 10 bits to represent the 1000 classes in AlexNet?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, papers, alexnet

I'm reading [the AlexNet paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks). In section 4, where the authors explain how they prevent overfitting, they mention

> Although the 1000 classes of ILSVRC make each training example impose 10 bits of constraint on the mapping from image to label".

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 10-bits ($2^{10} = 1024$) to represent 1000 classes.

Answer (score 1):

It takes at least 10 bits to represent any number between $1-1000$ because $2^{10} = 1024$. This means that if one was trying to represent 1 of the 1000 classes, one would need at least 10 bits. However, having these 10 bits set correctly for each input is really hard and would require overfitting to ensure it.